# Is it possible to emulate mixed abstract/deferred and regular procedures in Fortran 2003?

Tags: fortran, abstract-data-type

When I try to mix both regular procedures and deferred procedures in one abstract type, gfortran balks at any invocation of the regular procedures: 
" Error: Base object for type-bound procedure call at (1) is of ABSTRACT type 'tbody' "

```
    type, abstract  :: tBody
private
  ...
contains
  procedure                     :: init => new_Body
  ...
  procedure (contained), deferred   :: PointIn
end type tBody
abstract interface
  logical(LGT) pure function contained( Body, Point )
    import  :: tBody, tAffinePoint, LGT
    class(tBody), intent(IN)        :: Body
    type(tAffinePoint), intent(IN)  :: Point
  end function contained
end interface

subroutine newCuboid(  this, ... )
class(tCuboid), intent(OUT)     :: this
...

call this%tBody%init( ... )
....    [gfortran halts here]

end subroutine newCuboid
```

Is there a way to arrange the type tBody so that I can have both abstract, deferred procedures and regular, instantiated procedures?

Comment: Something not clear from your example code (but which I was assuming) - I presumed newCuboid was a subroutine overriding the binding init in the tCuboid type, hence the obvious ``call this%init( ... )`` would recurse.  If that's the case then it might be an idea to have that explicit in the example code.

Answer (score 5):

No.

There's a simple solution - replace `call this%tBody%init(...)` with `call new_Body(...)` (you may need to make appropriate accessibility changes).

Possibly feeble rationalisation - you are not resolving the procedure on the basis of the type of the reference (because that's hard coded), so don't use type bound procedure syntax.

Another solution in some cases is to split the type hierarchy further, so that the abstract type tBody has a non-abstract parent that hosts the initial implementation of the "not deferred" procedures.

Comment: Thanks. I like the second option better. The first option apparently can only be done by exposing new_Body as PUBLIC, making it no longer type-bound. That may create too much mischief during later maintenance.

Comment: But note the "feeble rationalisation" - this%tBody%binding, doesn't do type bound stuff anyway.  (Possibly flawed understanding follows...) Both the declare and dynamic types of this%tBody are type tBody, not the extension type (this has implications for the second option too).  (In a sense you are creating a non-polymorphic object of abstract type - which is why the syntax rules stop you - bindings of such a thing might not "exist").  Because you've specified the dynamic type you've effectively specified the specific procedure, just using different syntax.