# How do I call a super class method from a subclass when that super class contains deferred methods in fortran?

Tags: fortran

I trying to set up a parent class with two child subclasses. The parent class will contain at least one deferred method and at least one non-deferred method.

**Parent Class**

```
      TYPE, ABSTRACT :: parent
      CONTAINS
         PROCEDURE (parent_deferred_method), DEFERRED :: deferred_method
         PROCEDURE :: non_deferred_method => parent_non_deferred_method
      END TYPE

      ABSTRACT INTERFACE
         FUNCTION parent_deferred_method(this)
            IMPORT
            CLASS (parent), INTENT(in) :: this
            INTEGER                    :: parent_deferred_method
         END FUNCTION
      END INTERFACE

      CONTAINS

      FUNCTION parent_non_deferred_method(this)
         CLASS (parent), INTENT(in) :: this
         INTEGER                    :: parent_non_deferred_method

         parent_non_deferred_method = 1
      END FUNCTION
```

Because I have the a deferred method, I need to make the parent type as abstract. Now I want to define two child class. One child will not override the non-deferred method of the parent class.

**Child 1 Class**

```
      TYPE, EXTENDS(parent) :: child1
      CONTAINS
         PROCEDURE :: deferred_method => child1_deferred_method
      END TYPE

      CONTAINS

      FUNCTION child1_deferred_method(this)
         CLASS (child1), INTENT(in) :: this
         INTEGER                    :: child1_deferred_method

         child1_deferred_method = 2
      END FUNCTION
```

But the other will override. The problem I'm having is that I want to second child class to call the method of the parent class. However, this gives me an error since the parent class is `ABSTRACT`.

**Child 2 Class**

```
      TYPE, EXTENDS(parent) :: child2
         CONTAINS
         PROCEDURE :: deferred_method => child2_deferred_method
         PROCEDURE :: non_deferred_method => child2_non_deferred_method
      END TYPE

      CONTAINS

      FUNCTION child2_deferred_method(this)
         CLASS (child2), INTENT(in) :: this
         INTEGER                    :: child2_deferred_method

         child2_deferred_method = 3
      END FUNCTION

      FUNCTION child2_non_deferred_method(this)
         CLASS (child2), INTENT(in) :: this
         INTEGER                    :: child2_non_deferred_method

         child2_non_deferred_method = 4 +                                      &
     &      this%parent%non_deferred_method()
      END FUNCTION
```

How do I call a super class method when that super class contains deferred methods?

Comment: It would help if you show the error you are getting

Comment: Even better would be a complete program showing what you are trying to do - even if it doesn't compile. Then it would be easy for me to have a play.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523727/is-it-possible-to-emulate-mixed-abstract-deferred-and-regular-procedures-in-fort