# Fortran cannot compile call to procedure on abstract parent type

Tags: oop, fortran, gfortran, derived-types, fortran2003

I'm working on a large project where a particular group of objects has several layers of inheritance.  It's common for an object to have a method which first call's the parent object's version of that method, then performs some additional work that's specific to the child.

While this is a pattern I've followed many times, I recently discovered that if the parent class is `ABSTRACT`, gfortran 8.3.0 does not compiler.  Here is a MWE:

```
MODULE typeDef
TYPE,ABSTRACT :: parent
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE :: testFoo => testFooParent
ENDTYPE parent
TYPE,EXTENDS(parent) :: child
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE :: testFoo => testFooChild
ENDTYPE child

CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE testFooParent(this)
    CLASS(parent),INTENT(INOUT) :: this

    WRITE(*,*) 'parent'
  ENDSUBROUTINE testFooParent
  SUBROUTINE testFooChild(this)
    CLASS(child),INTENT(INOUT) :: this

    CALL this%parent%testFoo()
    WRITE(*,*) 'child'
  ENDSUBROUTINE testFooChild
ENDMODULE typeDef
PROGRAM bug

ENDPROGRAM
```

The error I receive is here:

```
bug.f90:20:13:

     CALL this%parent%testFoo()
             1
Error: Base object for type-bound procedure call at (1) is of ABSTRACT type ‘parent’
```

I am aware of no such reason that this should not work, but perhaps I've missed something in the standard?  If anyone can confirm for me that this is a bug before I go submit a potentially stupid bug report, that would be very helpful.

I am currently simply duplicating the parent class's behavior inside the child class's implementation.  In this particular case, that's not a big deal, but it could easily cause problems down the road.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523727/is-it-possible-to-emulate-mixed-abstract-deferred-and-regular-procedures-in-fort (there are a few others too). It is not a compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question.  It definitely looks to be the same issue.  That being said, I would dispute the claim that those answers prove it's not a compiler bug.  That asker was also using gfortran, and given that the question is 8 years old, it was a much older version of gfortran than I'm currently using.  Versions of gfortran 8 years ago were VERY bad with any sort of polymorphism, so it could still easily be a compiler bug.  I'll have to try with another compiler and see if I get the same results (if so, hopefully with a better explanation of why it's disallowed.)

Comment: If you happen to have some more concrete information on why it's not a bug (i.e., some reference to the fortran standard), that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The prohibition in the standard is F2018 C911 (and similar in earlier revisions) - which is to do with the parent component reference (that parent reference being used to nominate a procedure binding is secondary).  A reference to a parent component is not a polymorphic reference.  A parent component reference is a request for an object that has declared *and* dynamic type of the parent - something that has a fixed dynamic type is not polymorphic.  The restriction is for good reason - it does not make sense for something to have a dynamic type that is abstract.